# Apache jena to update remote endpoint

Tags: insert, sparql, rdf, endpoint

The current procedure we now often perform is to extract data from an endpoint, perform computational analysis, generate RDF files and manually load them back into the endpoint.

Now I was looking into automating this procedure using Apache Jena ARQ as these dependencies are currently used for the retrieval of information.

I manage to get it partially to work using INSERT statements but performing thousands if not millions of inserts one by one seem a bit inefficient to me. The second issue is that we sometimes have regex or " in a string and this needs to escaped but there are many exceptions.

Is there a way to either parse or iterate over an internal apache jena model statements and inject this directly into an endpoint?

We currently use graphdb but it would be great if this can be applied using a universal approach.

**Update**

I have updated the code to handle 10 statements at once not sure yet what eventually the limit will be...

```
public class EndpointTests extends TestCase {

    // Only for local testing
    public void testEndpoint() throws Throwable {
        String endpoint = "http://10.117.11.77:7200/repositories/Test";
        Domain domain = new Domain("file:///Users/jasperkoehorst/diana_interproscan_head.nt");

        StmtIterator statements = domain.getRDFSimpleCon().getModel().listStatements();
        String strInsert = "INSERT DATA { ";
        int insertCounter = 0;
        while (statements.hasNext()) {
            insertCounter = insertCounter + 1;

            Statement statement = statements.nextStatement();

            String subject = statement.getSubject().getURI();
            String predicate = statement.getPredicate().getURI();
            String object = statement.getObject().toString();
            if (statement.getObject().isURIResource()) {
                object = "<" + statement.getObject().toString() + ">";
            }

            if (statement.getObject().isLiteral()) {
                object = statement.getObject().asLiteral().getString();
                object = object.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
                object = object.replaceAll("\"","\\\\\"");
            }

            if (object.startsWith("http")) {
                object = "<" + object + ">";
            } else {
                object = "\"" + object + "\"";
            }

            strInsert = strInsert + "<" + subject + "> <" + predicate + "> " + object + " . ";

            if (insertCounter % 10 == 0) {
                System.out.println(insertCounter);
                strInsert = strInsert + " } ";
                UpdateRequest updateRequest = UpdateFactory.create(strInsert);
                UpdateProcessor updateProcessor = UpdateExecutionFactory.createRemote(updateRequest, endpoint + "/statements");
                updateProcessor.execute();
                strInsert = "INSERT DATA { ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"an internal apache jena model statements and inject this directly into an endpoint?"* - in the end it's still an HTTP request or not? I mean, you have to communicate with the remote endpoint. By the way, you can use a single `INSERT` statement with all triple inside.

Comment: For more convenience, you should work on `Dataset` objects instead and use [RDFConnection](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/rdfconnection/)

Comment: All the triples might be to much? I will do some testing to see the limits of a http request. I will look into how to use the RDFConnection.

Comment: I don't know about performance, but to cite from what I linked to: *"In addition to the SPARQL Graph Store Protocol, operations on whole datasets are provided for fetching (HTTP GET), adding data (HTTP POST) and setting the data (HTTP PUT) on a dataset URL. This assumes the remote server supported these REST-style operations. Apache Jena Fuseki does provide these."*

Comment: I would avoid building INSERT statements via String concatenation, at the very least use `StringBuilder`.  However as other commenters have pointed out there are much more better programmatic APIs to achieve the same thing